# Create XSD from database programmatically in C#

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, xsd

My DB schema has matured a lot. The XSD had increased in size and hence using Visual Studio 2008 designer is getting difficult. Is there a way I can automate the XSD generation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this tool while trying to solve a different problem.

Download: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mygeneration/

XSD Template: http://www.mygenerationsoftware.com/TemplateLibrary/Archive/?guid=59a03408-c96f-4baf-8171-b6bfe8725dab

Fairly simple.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this in previous lives using the catalog stored procedures that would list all tables, columns and indices, and run the resulting dataset against a templating engine (homebrewed at the time, but Codesmith would fit the bill 100%, or a clever xslt transform).

Here are the stored procs you can use : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182764.aspx

You can then either do the transform in-process or export the whole dataset to xml.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about datasets, cant you just drag everything onto the designer surface?

Answer (score 0):

[Altova XmlSpy](http://www.altova.com/xmlspy.html) has build-in functionality to convert a database structure to a kind of XSD. It might not be what you need, though.